UltraZed EV SOM: Interrupt Handler Not Triggering After Stop Command and Restart
I'm working on a project using the UltraZed EV SOM, and I've encountered an issue with interrupt handling in my custom kernel module.
Issue Description:
I have two video modes: "Normal" and "RAW", and I have 12 interrupt handlers. Four of these interrupt handlers are used in both modes.
1. CASE
When I start RAW recording, the dru_irq_vid11 interrupt handler works as expected and records successfully. However, if I start normal recording and then switch back to RAW recording, the dru_irq_vid11 interrupt handler does not trigger at all.
2. CASE

Initially, when I start a normal recording, the dru_irq_vid11 interrupt handler works as expected.
After sending a stopall command and then initiating a RAW recording, the dru_irq_vid11 interrupt handler does not trigger at all.
When the interrupt handler is supposed to trigger, it behaves as if no data is being received.

Debugging Steps Taken:

Verified that the dru_irq_vid11 handler is correctly registered and enabled.
Checked the video_mode and VID15_ENABLE values, and they appear correct.
Ensured that the stopall command is functioning correctly.

/*init dru interrupt VID11*/
printk("Geldim, Gördüm, Gidiyorum. \n");
        r_irq = platform_get_resource(pdev, IORESOURCE_IRQ, 10);
    
        if (!r_irq) {
            dev_err(&pdev->dev, "No IRQ VID11 resource defined.\n");
            return -ENXIO;
        }
    dru_dev->irq = r_irq->start;
        printk("IRQ VID11 registered at %d\n", r_irq->start);
        ret = request_irq(dru_dev->irq, dru_irq_vid11,IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING, "dru_irq_vid11", dev);

    if (ret) {
        dev_err(dev, "Failed to request interrupt VID11: %d\n", ret);
        return ret;
        }
    printk("ret Value : %d\n",ret);
    printk("dev Value : %d\n",dev);
    ret=0;
static irqreturn_t dru_irq_vid11(int irq, void *dev_id)
{
    struct device *dev = dev_id;
    int num;
    int vid_mode=readl(video_mode);
    num = vid_mode & VID15_ENABLE;


    printk("Reach -2- \n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "vid_mode Value : %d\n", vid_mode);
    printk(KERN_INFO "num Value : %d\n", num);
    
    int vid11_buffercount=readl(base_part3buffercount);
    int vid15_buffercount=readl(base_part4buffercount);

    if(num != VID15_ENABLE){
        vid11_buffercount = (vid11_buffercount & 0x0000fffff) >> 16;
        dev_err(dev, "VID11 Frame Count: %d\n",vid11_buffercount);
        write_mchar_vid11(dev,vid11_buffercount);   
    }
    else{
        vid15_buffercount = (vid15_buffercount & 0x0000fffff) >> 16;
        dev_err(dev, "VID15 Frame Count: %d\n",vid15_buffercount);
        write_mchar_vid15(dev,vid15_buffercount);
    }

    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

Debugging Steps Taken:

Verified that the dru_irq_vid11 handler is correctly registered and enabled.
Checked the video_mode and VID15_ENABLE values, and they appear correct.
Ensured that the stopall command is functioning correctly.

I started by verifying that the interrupt handler (dru_irq_vid11) was correctly registered and enabled. I also checked that the video_mode and VID15_ENABLE values were correct. After sending the stopall command, I expected the dru_irq_vid11 handler to trigger again when I initiated RAW recording. However, the handler did not trigger at all, even though the values appeared correct and the system behaved as if no data was being received. I added debug prints to confirm the handler wasn't being called, and ensured that all memory addresses and register values were correct.
